# How to switch between tabline and buffers view in vim airline?

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I've been using vim-airline on vim-8.0 and it displays tabs in the `tabline` and when I mouse left-click (with mouse input enabled) on filename on the far right hand side of the tabline the view switches to `buffers` (if I have enabled the option: `let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_buffers = 1`).

But so far I can't seem to find a way to get back to tab view again? This may just be a standard vim tab navigation issue as even with show_buffers disabled when I click on the right hand side of the tabline I get stuck with viewing just that file.

A solution using the mouse would be preferable but a vim command would be fine too.